# Game of nim: Issues with loops and program in general

Tags: c++

I do not know how to make my program repeat without a do-while loop. The loop makes my program repeat saying "the mode is set to dumb" and "it is your turn." I could really use some help on completing this program because it is homework and due tonight at 9:30. The game is taking marbles out of a pile and the person to take the last marble loses.

```
 // new project 1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
int smartcomputer(int);
int dumbcomputer(int, int);
int playerturn(int, int);
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    bool flag = true;
    int marbletake = 0;
    string dumborsmart;
    srand(time(0));
    int pilesize = rand() % (100 - 10) + 10;
    cout << "Hello, Welcome to the game of Nim. Two players alternatively take marbles from a pile." << endl;
    cout << "Each move a player must take at least one marble but at most half of the marbles." << endl;
    cout << "Enter dumb for dumb mode and smart for smart mode." << endl;
    getline(cin, dumborsmart);
    do {
        if (dumborsmart == "dumb") {
            cout << "The mode is set to dumb." << endl;//set to dumb

            bool turn = rand() % 2;
            if (turn = true) {
                cout << "It is your turn" << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << "It is the bots turn" << endl;
            }
            if (turn = false) {      //not player's turn=false
                if (dumborsmart == "dumb") {
                    pilesize = dumbcomputer(marbletake, pilesize);
                    bool turn = true;
                }
                else {
                    pilesize = smartcomputer(pilesize);
                    bool turn = true;
                }
            }
        }
        else {

            pilesize = playerturn(marbletake, pilesize);
            bool turn = false;
        }

    } while (pilesize != 1);
    return 0;
}

int playerturn(int marbletake, int pilesize){
    cout << "It is your turn. Marbles remaining in pile: " << pilesize << endl;
    cout << "Enter a number of marbles to remove from the pile" << endl;
    cin >> marbletake;
    if (marbletake > 1 && marbletake < (pilesize / 2)) {
        pilesize = pilesize - marbletake;
        cout << "Number of marbles in the pile: " << pilesize << endl;
        if (pilesize ==1) {
            cout << "You win. The bot is forced to take the last marble." << endl;
            system("pause");

        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "Error, please remove a number of marbles greater than 0 or less than half the pile." << endl;
        cin >> marbletake;
        pilesize = pilesize - marbletake;
        cout << "Number of marbles in the pile: " << pilesize << endl;
        if (pilesize ==1) {
            cout << "You win. The bot is forced to take the last marble." << endl;

        }
    }

    return pilesize;

}
int smartcomputer(int pilesize){
    cout << "The bot is removing marbles from the pile." << endl;
    if (pilesize > 63) {
        pilesize = 63;
    }
    else if (pilesize > 31 && pilesize < 63) {
        pilesize = 31;
    }
    else if (pilesize > 15 && pilesize < 31) {
        pilesize = 15;
    }
    else if (pilesize > 7 && pilesize < 15) {
        pilesize = 7;
    }
    else if (pilesize > 3 && pilesize < 7) {
        pilesize = 3;
    }
    else {
        pilesize = pilesize - rand() % (pilesize / 2) + 1;
    }
    cout << "Number of marbles in the pile: " << pilesize << endl;
    if (pilesize ==1) {
        cout << "You lose. You are forced to take the last marble." << endl;

    }

    return pilesize;
}
int dumbcomputer(int marbletake, int pilesize){
    cout << "The bot is removing marbles from the pile." << endl;
    pilesize = (pilesize - rand() % (pilesize / 2) + 1); // bot takes marbles from pile(half pile size-1)
    cout << "Number of marbles in the pile: " << pilesize << endl;
    if (pilesize ==1) {
        cout << "You lose. You are forced to take the last marble." << endl;

    }

    return pilesize;

}
```

Comment: Are you asking why the stuff in `if (turn = false) {` doesn't run?

Comment: Use `==` for comparison, `=` is for assignment.

Comment: Yeah i'm asking why the program repeats "the mode is set to dumb" and "it is your turn" over and over. I think its the while at the bottom but, i don't know how else to make it repeat.

Comment: Okay. Lemme give it a go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the `cout` line that prints the mode out of the loop:

```
cout << "The mode is set to " << dumborsmart << "\n";
do {
    ...
} while (pilesize != 1);
```

Also, `if (turn = true)` and `if (turn = false)` won't work, you need to use `==` there. But it's even better to write `if (turn)` and `if (!turn)`.

And in your `else if (pilesize > X && pilesize < Y)` tests, you're skipping the cases where `pilesize == Y`. You should just remove `&& pilesize < Y`, since it's already guaranteed by the fact that the previous `if` failed, then these boundary cases won't be skipped.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I'm gonna change all of the stuff you said and see how it goes.